# Is @FunctionalInterface just a marker interface or more than that?

Tags: lambda, java-8, functional-programming, marker-interfaces

I guess @FuntionalInterface is present even before Java 8 (although not directly named as `@FunctionalInterface` the interfaces such as `Comparator` and `Comparable` that have single method). Is it just a marker interface or will it trigger compiler checks to make sure that the interface contains one and only one method which can be used in lambda expression ?

Comment: There is no need to guess, or waste time asking questions on the Internet. Just read the Javadoc. There it states clearly 'Since 1.8', and answers your other questions as well.

Comment: @user207421 Apologies for that. Modified question to be more meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not even a marker. From the [`@FunctionalInterface` API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html):

> An **informative** annotation type used to indicate that an interface type declaration is intended to be a *functional interface* as defined by the Java Language Specification.

(Highlighting added by me)

It is additionally annotated with [`@Documented`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/Documented.html), thus the presence of this annotation will be present in, for example, javadocs.

It provides, however, some compile time safety. If the annotated interface has more than one non-default method, we will receive a compilation error.

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/vh10hR)